# Unable to restore sql file in postgresql on windows

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to import sql file in postgresql but unable to do. I  tried pgAdmin 4 to restore sql file. I get the error (pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive).

I've also tried to do this with the command prompt but unable to do.

If I do

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin>psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres gorkha < D:/gorkha.sql
```

It returns

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
REVOKE
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190457/discussion-on-question-by-palistha-unable-to-restore-sql-file-in-postgresql-on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command to restore an archived backup using `pg_restore`

```
pg_restore -U <username> -d <dbname> -1 <filename>.sql
```

for text/sql based backup you can try

```
psql -U <username> -d <dbname> -1 -f <filename>.sql
```

Comment: `pg_restore` will not accept an SQL script. It supports the `-Fc`, `-Fd`, and `-Ft` format options, but only `pg_dump` allows `-Fp`. SQL backups are meant to be restored using `psql`. If this command is working for you, it just means that you've put an `.sql` extension on a binary backup file.

Comment: I can't see why it won't accept, I answered after performing the operation

Comment: Sorry, pg_restore didn't work . When I did psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres newDBname < D:\backup.sql, it was working for other sql file, but unable to restore the file which I want.

Comment: Nick Barnes -Any suggestion please?

Comment: this seems something specific to your backup file

Comment: @NickBarnes I realized that file was actually a binary, I've updated my answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Create a DB like (Employees)
- Lets say you have a employees.sql file which you want to restore
- postgres is your username
- AT command prompt you are in the same folder with employees.sql
  Code sample is:

  psql -U postgres -d Employees < employees.sql

Answer (score 1):

Follow This Steps:

- Open pgAdmin and open Servers -> PostgreSQL 14 -> Databases,
- And Choose your DB and right click and click on the **PSQL Tool**[image]
- If you not set your binary path and you get this alert[image]
- and click File option in top of pgadmin & open preference[image]
- Click The file icon and set the following path and Save[image]
- Final Step Open your Sql File in VSCode or note pad and copy then paste it on the  **PSQL Tool in pgAdmin**
  **Its Work For Me**
  If any Error and Convert SQL To PGSQL (more online tools are available)
  and the copy paste in to PSQL Tool in pgAdmin